# index.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I'm new to MERN development. I'm trying to build a learning management system by following an old tutorial. But I ended up getting this error:

```
> ..\server\middlewares\index.js:1
> import {expressJwt}  from "express-jwt"; SyntaxError: The requested
> module
> ../server/node_modules/express-jwt/dist/index.js'
> does not provide an export named 'default'
>     at Object.<anonymous> ..\server\middlewares\index.js:1)
>     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
>     at Object.<anonymous> ..\server\routes\auth.js:1)
>     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10) [nodemon] app crashed -
> waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The relevant code is as follows:

**server>middlewares>index.js :**

```
import expressJwt from "express-jwt";

export const requireSignin = expressJwt({
  getToken: (req, res) => req.cookies.token,
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  algorithms: ["HS256"],
});
```

**server>routes>auth.js :**

```
import express from "express";

const router = express.Router();

// middleware
import { requireSignin } from "../middlewares";

// controllers
import { register, login, logout, currentUser } from "../controllers/auth";

router.post("/register", register);
router.post("/login", login);
router.get("/logout", logout);
router.get("/current-user", requireSignin, currentUser);

module.exports = router;
```

I have also used this format for middlewares:

1.

```
import {expressJwt}  from "express-jwt";

export const requireSignin = expressJwt({
  getToken: (req, res) => req.cookies.token,
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  algorithms: ["HS256"],
});
```

2. 

```
import {expressJwt}  from "express-jwt";

const requireSignin = expressJwt({
  getToken: (req, res) => req.cookies.token,
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  algorithms: ["HS256"],
});

export default requireSignin;
```

but this doesn't help at all.

Here is the package.JSON file (for server):

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -r esm server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-jwt": "^7.7.7",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.15",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting pictures of error messages.

Comment: Also, **read the documentation**!! [It says](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt): `expressjwt` not `expressJwt`

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to import in this case is:

```js
import {expressjwt} from "express-jwt";
```

(lowercase `j`)

Another thing to try in general when you encounter errors like

> The requested module [...] does not provide an export named 'default'

is using a *star-import*:

```js
import * as X from "x";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but didn't work for me.

Comment: Hmm, `import {expressjwt} from "express-jwt"` works for me. What error do you get?

Comment: I have rechecked, and now it's working. Thank you for taking the time to read this, brother. I really appreciate it.